# file gets converted to base 64 in dart html http call

Tags: javascript, dart

I am trying to upload a file  from dart HTML SDK , it is getting uploaded but it does not get uploaded in actual file instead it gets uploaded in base 64 :
here is the code:

```
  InputElement uploadInput = querySelector('#customFile');
  uploadInput.onChange.listen((e) {
    // read file content as dataURL
    final files = uploadInput.files;
    if (files.length == 1) {
      final file = files[0];
      print(file);
      final reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onLoad.listen((e) {
        sendData(reader.result);
      });
      reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
    }
  });

sendData(dynamic data) async {
  var url1 = 'uploadurl goes here';
  var uploadStatus = await http.put(
      url1,
      body:data,
      headers: {'x-ms-blob-type':'BlockBlob',
        'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}
  );
//  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
  print(uploadStatus.statusCode);
}
```

and here is the content of the CSV file :

Query,Service name,remark,feedback from aws team,date,status

This is my import :

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I found that instead of readAsdataUrl, readAsArrayBuffer solves the problem

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```